# How to export .glb or .3mf to .fbx with colors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, fbx

I miss old paint 3d with export to .fbx, and i must put my paint 3d object in unity 3d with color.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see the site guidelines on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular this question needs more information about the problem and what you've tried already - what do you mean with colors?

Comment: i mean you can draw on your model in paint 3d, and its textures is colors. I tried convert glb to fbx, but there is no textures in fbx